# Edit Total Number of Pages in Footer SelectPDF

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf

I am converting html page to pdf using HtmlToPdf() of SelectPDF. Since html content is big, I am breaking it in half and creating 2 PDFs.

I am struggling to edit the total_pages in the footer to display actual total number of the pages, not only the current document; as well as  page_number to display the actual page number in the context of both PDFs.

How can I assess {page_number} and  {total_pages} to calculate proper values? All examples I found use PdfDocument(), not HtmlToPdf().

```
Dim converter As New HtmlToPdf()
Dim text As New PdfTextSection(0, 10, "Page: {page_number} of {total_pages} ")
text.HorizontalAlign = PdfTextHorizontalAlign.Center
converter.Footer.Add(text)
```

I am tagging both C# and VB since SelectPDF is for both languages, and relevant sample from either one will work for me.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Today I've stumbled upon the same issue and I have found a work-around for the problem. The converter was able to show page numbers for it's the generated document but can't be aware of multiple generated files (you can't access the page properties) so all my pages I concatenated were showing Page 1 of 1.

First I define one PdfDocument (see it as the main document) and I use HtmlToPdf to append html converted files to this main document.

```
// Create converter
converter = new HtmlToPdf();    
PdfTextSection text = new PdfTextSection(0, 10, "Page: {page_number} of {total_pages}  ", new Font("Arial", 8));
text.HorizontalAlign = PdfTextHorizontalAlign.Right;
converter.Footer.Add(text);

// Create main document
pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
```

Then I add pages (from html) using this method

```
public void AddPage(string htmlPage)
{
    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlPage);
    pdfDocument.Append(doc);
    converter.Footer.TotalPagesOffset += doc.Pages.Count;
    converter.Footer.FirstPageNumber += doc.Pages.Count;
}
```

This results in correct page numbers for the main document. The same trick could be used for splitting files and page numbers over multiple documents like you described.

EDIT: In case you don't see any page numbering using the HtmlToPdf converter, don't forget to set following property:

```
converter.Options.DisplayFooter = true;
```

Comment: Thank you! old but gold, I'm glad I'm able to stumble your solution

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source library called itextsharp that will help get total page count.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
namespace GetPages_PDF
{
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
      {
       // Right side of equation is location of YOUR pdf file
        string ppath = "C:\\aworking\\Hawkins.pdf";
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(ppath);
        int numberOfPages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfPages);
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can stamp text also on the page but you will need to add the location to where it needs to go.

link: http://crmhunt.com/how-to-modify-pdf-file-using-itextsharp/

hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Doing a second pass with a general purpose PDF library surely is an way to address the problem. But the OP clearly mentions that he is using SelectPDF and is searching a solution working with that library.

Comment: iTextSharp is not solution for this particular problem since 1) I am adding that info to footer while creating PDF. 2 )I am looking for the way to update not only the total number of pages, but also correct number for the current page within  the scope of total number of pages between 2 pdfs. E.g if each of 2 pdfs have 5 pages, then 1st page for the 2nd document should have in the footer: "Page: 6 of 10". I am trying to figure out how to add that page offset or how to get direct access to {page_number} and {total_pages} -  values defined by SelectPDF.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following properties:

- FirstPageNumber - Controls the page number for the first page being
  rendered.
- TotalPagesOffset - Controls the total number of pages
  offset in the generated pdf document.

More details here:
http://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/HtmlToPdfHeadersAndFooters.htm

Comment: I need to know value of {total_pages} generated in pdf  in order to know value for TotalPagesOffset  and set FirstPageNumber. Generating of pdf pages happens after Footer.FirstPageNumber option is set.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above did not work for me as I was trying to merge multiple PDFs with different orientations. bonnoj's answer did add page numbers but they were incorrect and I couldn't find a way to correct them. So I took a different approach - I created a PDF, then for each HTML page I added a pdfPage and then added a PdfHtmlElement to that page. Finally I loop over the pages and add a custom footer to each page. This may not be the most efficient way to do this but it's the only way that I could find that added the footer in the correct place when mixing portrait and landscape pages. Hopefully it will save somebody else spending hours playing with different properties.

```
var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(PdfStandard.Full);

foreach (var (html, pdfPageOrientation) in pages)
{
    var page = pdfDocument.AddPage(PdfCustomPageSize.A4, new PdfMargins(marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom));
    page.Orientation = pdfPageOrientation;
    
    var pdfHtmlElement = new PdfHtmlElement(html, "");    

    page.Add(pdfHtmlElement);
}


var pdfFont = pdfDocument.AddFont(PdfStandardFont.Helvetica);
pdfFont.Size = 12;

foreach (PdfPage page in pdfDocument.Pages)
{
  var customFooter = pdfDocument.AddTemplate(page.PageSize.Width, 30);
  var pdfFooterTextElement = new PdfTextElement(0, 15,
    pageFooterText,
    pdfFont)
  {
    HorizontalAlign = PdfTextHorizontalAlign.Right,
    VerticalAlign = PdfTextVerticalAlign.Bottom,
  };

  customFooter.Add(pdfFooterTextElement);

  page.CustomFooter = customFooter;
}

pdfDocument.Save(stream);
```